# Count how many times a value appears in dictionary ? (PYTHON 3)

Tags: python, database, list, loops, dictionary

Suppose i have a list of names like this:  names = [ 'James','Bruce','John']

and a dictionary like this:

```
                dict= { 
                     'James':{ 'Job' :'Engineer'},          
                       'Bruce':{'Job' : 'Engineer'},
                        'John':{'Job' :'Doctor'}
                         }
```

I want to create a dictionary that count how many times 'Doctor' or 'Engineer' appear in the dictionary so the output will be like : `count = {'Doctor':1, 'Engineer':2}.`

My solution is to create a list of the jobs and then count how many times that job appears in the list so it goes like :

```
job_list=[]
count ={}
for k in names:
      job_list.append(dict[k]['Job'] #( so i can have a list like this:
                           #job_list =  ['Engineer','Engineer','Doctor'])
for i in job_list:
    count[i] = 0 
for i in job_list:
    count[i] += 1
```

is there faster way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. In the sense of [mcve], please watch out your provided code is executable. The dictionary is not valid python code. That said, you have a _nested_ dictionary here. Do you really have to stick with this setup? I think there are better ways for storing this kind of data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to import anything then your code can be improved by looping through the dictionary just a single time. I'm calling the dict `d`

```
job_counts = {}
for k in names:
    job = d[k]['Job']
    if job in job_counts:
        job_counts[job] += 1
    else:
        job_counts[job] = 1

print(job_counts)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Counter method in collections library to achieve this in one line:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([dict[person]['Job'] for person in dict])
```